# what is force keyword and what happens when it is set to true/false?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I'm learning NodeJs from some website. And while taking the course sequelize is introduced after moving on the concept a new keyword is used called force which is set to true.

What is the force keyword and why it is used?

MYSQL, Sequelize, Nodejs, npm

```
sequelize
  .sync({ force: true })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If force is true, each Model will run DROP TABLE IF EXISTS, before it
>   tries to create its own table

For more info read [instance-method-sync](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-method-sync)

Regards.

Comment: @sravani-nagavarapu  Please upvote the answer if it was usefull to you.. so that others can benefit from it..

Answer (score 1):

Using force recreates the tables even though they already exist. With force at true, the sync will complitely empty your database and recreate empty tables.